# Webmin cron job can't access function on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, webmin

Hi I create a new scheduled cron job on webmin

My command is php

```
/var/www/admin-mywebsite/index.php croncontroller cronfunction
```

it returns the home page of my website on Codeigniter

I tried on an other website on the same server and it is the same : it returns the homepage.

If I try on navigator :

```
www.admin-mywebsite/croncontroller/cronfunction
```

it works

Why my cronjob doesn't access to mycontroller and function in my command?

Comment: Do you want to allow a function that will be used by a that can be initiated by anyone?

Comment: Is your controller in a place that will allow direct access?

Comment: kisaragi: yes I can access by my navigator there are no login needed

Comment: liam I will put a $this->input->is_cli_request() after that my cron job can access this function